# Ignore rows based on Row Length or first character in Fixed Width file - File Helpers - C#

Tags: c#, text-files, skip, filehelpers, fixed-width

I have a fixed width text file and I am reading it through `FileHelpers` library. Right now I am ignoring First two rows and last three rows using this syntax

```
[IgnoreFirst(2)]
[IgnoreLast(3)]
```

But I want to ignore rows by their length or if row is empty or if first letter is A or T.
I found out that I can use syntax `[SkipThisRecord]` but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `IgnoreEmptyLines` attribute and the `ConditionalRecord` attribute.

```
    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
    [ConditionalRecord(RecordCondition.ExcludeIfBegins, "A")] 
    public class ConditionalType1 
    { 
       /// etc.
    }
```

There are several options for `RecordCondition` such as `ExcludeIfMatchRegex`. See the [docs](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/FileHelpers-Stable/FileHelpers/RecordCondition).

Comment: It gives me error when I add two `Conditional Record`, one for A and one for T, It says Duplicate 'Conditional Record' Attribute

Comment: You can use a regular expression for that case, or better yet add an interface to your class: INotifyRead and in the the method OnBeforeReadRecord you can skype the current line with any condition you want